# What is the proper MvcContrib 3 syntax for this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvccontrib

I inherited an ASP.NET MVC 1 website using MVCContrib 1.5 that I'm trying to upgrade to MVC 3 and MVCContrib 3.

The website had the following when using `Html.Grid`

```
.Columns(column=>{
  column.For("Yes").Action(p =>{%>
    <td>
      <%=this.Hidden("category[" + i +"].Id").Value(p.Id)%>
      <%=this.RadioButton("category[" + i + "].Interested").Value("true") %>
    </td>
  <%});

  column.For("No").Action(p =>{%>
    <td>
      <%=this.RadioButton("category[" + i + "].Interested").Value("false") %> 
    </td>                                                       
  <%});
})
```

In MvcContrib `.For("Yes")` is no longer valid syntax to create the column with the string as the heading.

To get it to work I had to change it to `.For(c=>"Yes")` and I had to add `.Named("Yes")` to get the header text back. As far as I know, `c=>"Yes"` doesn't actually do anything useful. What should go there? Or should I just leave it if it's not doing any harm?

Also, `.Action` is deprecated and it says to use `.Custom` instead. How would I convert the above?

```
column.Custom(p => {%>
  <td style="text-align:center">
    <%=this.Hidden("category[" + i + "].Id").Value(p.Id)%>
    <%=this.RadioButton("category[" + i + "].Interested").Value("true") %>
  </td>
<% }).Named("Yes");
```

This expects a return value, I'm not sure what to put and can't find many examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
column.Custom(
    @<text>
         <td style="text-align:center">
             @this.Hidden("category[" + i + "].Id").Value(item.Id)
             @this.RadioButton("category[" + i + "].Interested").Value("true")
         </td>
     </text>
).Named("Yes");
```

Answer (score 1):

The `For()` method is used for when you just want to show the value of a property - so you could use it like:

```
column.For(p => p.Id).Named("Yes");
```

Note you don't have to use `Named()` if you've given the Id property a `[Display(Name="Yes")]` attributed on the model, as this will be used by default.

You can use `Custom()` when you want to display some html you've crafted, so you can just return an MvcHtmlString. With razor syntax it could look something like:

```
column.Custom(p => @Html.Partial("IdPartial",p.Id));
```